# Writing to PostgreSQL database in Python with SQLalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to write to my postgres database using Python in my google Colab notebook but am getting this error when I try the pandas "to_sql" function.

Here's the code: (this part raises no errors)

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2

conn= psycopg2.connect(
    host = "hostIP",
    dbname = "dbname", 
    user="postgres",
    password="pass"
)
df = pd.read_csv("https://data.messari.io/api/v1/assets/btc/metrics/price/time-series?start=2021-01-01&end=2021-02-02&interval=1d&format=csv")

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df['timestamp'].astype(str)

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:pass@host/dbname")
```

The error is raised when i try to run to.sql (function below):

```
df.to_sql('dbname', con=engine, if_exists='append', index = False)

TypeError
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py in do_executemany(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    907                 template=executemany_values,
    908                 fetch=bool(context.compiled.returning),
--> 909                 **kwargs
    910             )
    911 

TypeError: execute_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fetch'
```

I'm able to successfully connect to the postgres instance, and receive no errors after creating my 'engine' variable.

The datatypes in the pandas dataframe i am attemping to upload are:

```
timestamp     object
open         float64
high         float64
low          float64
close        float64
volume       float64
dtype: object
```

I think it may be an issue with the timestamp column datatype but i am not sure what the equivalent should be set to in Postgres.

Comment: How did you install packages for this environment? It looks like you have incompatible versions of `psycopg2` and `pandas` try uninstalling and the re-installing using conda

Comment: Google Colab handles version control so i didnt install anything, I simply used the import commands.

Comment: Ah, ok. In that case I'm not sure.

Comment: In order to better address your issue, could you share your code and also the full log error ?

Comment: updated with the full code

Comment: You wrote that the part of the code you shared runs successfully and I do not see the `to_sql()` function within it. Where and how do you use it ?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes The "to.sql" line is right above where i pasted the error message in the same code block

Comment: I was having the same issue. Found the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934750/source-of-the-unexpected-keyword-argument-fetch-error-in-pandas-to-sql

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting "unexpected argumet Fetch" from pandas df.to_sql,

add method = 'multi'

df.to_sql('dbname', con=engine, if_exists='append', index = False, **method = 'multi'**)